# How strcpy is being used to store values in a constant variable?

Tags: c, data-structures, struct, unions

I **found this example code from a practice test online** , How is the statement 
`strcpy(e1.name, "K");` valid, but the statement `e1.age=10;` is not ?Any reason .Please clarify.

Observed the `o/p` on Gcc as : `K 0 0.000000`

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct employee
{
    char name[15];
    int age;
    float salary;
};
const struct employee e1;

int main()
{
    strcpy(e1.name, "K"); // How strcpy is being used to store values in a    
                          // constant variable e1 .
    //e1.age=10; // not valid 
    printf("%s %d %f", e1.name, e1.age, e1.salary);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I think, your `union` should really be a `struct`.

Comment: Both GCC and clang complain when fed this code. You're missing an include too.

Comment: @ExP I already said that its from a practice test .Not mine

Comment: Ok now i made it struct

Comment: `*((int *)&(e1.age))=18` will work, without compilation warnings!

Comment: @Bechir, not if `e1` gets put in read-only memory, it won't.

Comment: @CarlNorum True. And then the `strcpy` will also not work. Isn't it lovely when practice tests rely on specific manifestations of undefined behaviour?

Answer (score 1):

When you access `age`, the compiler knows the that `e1` is `const` and forbids the write.

When on the other hand, you call `strcpy`, a pointer is passed to a function that is implemented in a (standard-)library. Since it's just a memory address, this library will just perform its write operation.

This should not be allowed, since the pointer is actually a memory address of a `const` object. The compiler will tell you that this is not allows but only produces a warning. Strictly speaking, this warning should be an error.

Answer (score 1):

To answer your first question, strcpy is storing the given name in the name field by iterating through the char array as well as the characters of the string literal, saving a copy of each. When the end of the source string is reached, a null char should be found and copied over to the destination. The null char indicates the end of the string, and it is very important that it is copied over. If it is not, your program may read past the end of the array, leading to segfaults or exposing you to buffer overrun attacks. In your case, since the name array has a length of 15, you should not copy over names longer than 14 characters.

The biggest problem with this code is the use of a union instead of a struct. Unions work like structs, but the memory for each field is saved in the same location. For this reason, you should only set one of the fields.